# vertical alignment of different units with siunitx

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx, nicematrix

I am trying to align the comma, but I am not able to. I have already looked for the solutions on the forum but I just can not find a working solution. There must be something I am overlooking. Also there is a problem with the last column header, it is not showing completely and I don't know how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt, fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                
\usepackage[lf, p, sflf, sfp]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[stretch=10, shrink=10, final]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[detect-all, locale=DE, detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}      
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}        
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}             

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{15cm}{>{}C{0.02\textwidth}L{0.32\textwidth}*{4}{Y}}
        \CodeBefore
        \rowcolor{yellow}{1}
        \Body
        \toprule
        \RowStyle{\footnotesize\bfseries}
        \# & {test} & Häufigkeit & \bm{$\mathsf{\overline{R1}}$} & R2& Problemwertindex \\
        \midrule
        A & a      & 6   & 5   & 30  & \SI{45.4}{\percent} \\
        B & b      & 8   & 2   & 16  & \SI{24.2}{\percent} \\
%       C & c      & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ \\
        D & d      & 2   & 5   & 10  & \SI{15.2}{\percent} \\
        E & e      & 2   & 3   & 6   & \SI{9.1}{\percent} \\
%       F & f & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ \\
        G & g      & 1   & 4   & 4   & \SI{ 6.1}{\percent} \\
        \midrule
          & Total  & 19  & 3,8 & 66  & \SI{100.0}{\percent} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should (1) add an image, (2) not use `\SI` in the cells, then we cannot align them. I'd probably list `\%` in the header instead of repeating it through the column.  The `\SI` column should then be made using the `S` column like `S[table-format=3.1]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For aligning numbers in the last column you should use `S` column type which is  defined in `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt, fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf, p, sflf, sfp]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[stretch=10, shrink=10, final]{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[detect-all, locale=DE, detect-weight]{siunitx}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{15cm}{>{}C{0.02\textwidth}L{0.32\textwidth}*{3}{Y} S[table-format=3.1{\%}] <{\%}}
        \CodeBefore
        \rowcolor{yellow}{1}
        \Body
        \toprule
        \RowStyle{\footnotesize\bfseries}
        \# & {test} & Häufigkeit & \bm{$\mathsf{\overline{R1}}$} & R2& \multicolumn{1}{c}{Problemwertindex} \\
        \midrule
        A & a      & 6   & 5   & 30  &  45.4    \\
        B & b      & 8   & 2   & 16  &  24.2    \\
%       C & c      & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ \\
        D & d      & 2   & 5   & 10  &  15.2    \\
        E & e      & 2   & 3   & 6   &   9.1    \\
%       F & f & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ & $-$ \\
        G & g      & 1   & 4   & 4   &   6.1    \\
        \midrule
          & Total  & 19  & 3,8 & 66  & 100.0    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabularX}
\end{document}
```

After three conpilation the result is:

[image]

**Addendum:**
For exercise the same table with use of `tabularray` package. MWE need only one compilation:

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt, fontsize=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lf, p, sflf, sfp]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}
\usepackage[stretch=10, shrink=10, final]{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all, locale=DE, detect-weight}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{width=15cm,
                 colspec = {Q[c,0.02\linewidth]
                            Q[l,0.32\linewidth]
                       *{3}{X[c]}
                            S[table-format=3.1{\%}]
                            },
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, bg=yellow},
                 }
    \toprule
\#  & test   & Häufigkeit & $\bm{\overline{R1}}$ & R2    & {{{Problemwertindex}}} \\
    \midrule
A   & a     & 6   & 5   & 30  &  45.4\,\%     \\
B   & b     & 8   & 2   & 16  &  24.2\,\%     \\
% C  & c     & --  & --  & --  &  --  \\
D   & d     & 2   & 5   & 10  &  15.2\,\%     \\
E   & e     & 2   & 3   & 6   &   9.1\,\%     \\
% F  & f     & --  & --  & --  & --  \\
G   & g     & 1   & 4   & 4   &   6.1\,\%     \\
    \midrule
    & Total & 19  & 3,8 & 66  & 100.0\,\%     \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]